# Hover on one element causes hovering effect on other element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseleave

I have to create the effect of bordered  when I hover over  element and vice versa.

I managed to do it, but the problem is that every time I hover over one of those elements I cancel the hovering effect on the element I was hovering over.

When I hover over  with id="12345img"  gets border and  with id="12345a" gets color effect. When I do it vice versa it also works, but only for the first time I'm hovering over it.

This is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.portfolioProject a').hover(function () {
            var idElement = this.id;
            $("#" + idElement.replace('a', '') + "img").css('border', '2px solid #cdfc5d');
            $("#" + idElement + "a").css('color', '#cdfc5d');
        });

        $('.portfolioProject a').mouseleave(function () {
            var idElement = this.id
            $("#" + idElement.replace('a', '') + "img").css('border', 'none');
            $("#" + idElement + "a").css('color', 'white');
        });

        $('.portfolioImage img').hover(function () {
            var idElement = this.id;
            $("#" + idElement.replace('img', '') + "a").css('color', '#cdfc5d');
            $("#" + idElement + "img").css('border', '2px solid #cdfc5d');
        });

        $('.portfolioImage img').mouseleave(function () {
            var idElement = this.id
            $("#" + idElement.replace('img', '') + "a").css('color', 'white');
            $("#" + idElement + "img").css('border', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is how to fix it to make it work every time.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/q8JZy/)

Comment: can you throw up your demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I'll put it there in a minute.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/q8JZy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to create CSS class for the mouse hover effect, Then you just Have to Toggle the class on event:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".portfolioImageWrapper").on('mouseenter mouseleave', ".img", function () {
                  $(this).toggleClass('imgHover');
                  $("#" + (this.id).replace('img', '') + "a").toggleClass('imgHover');  
              });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class='portfolioProject'>
    <ul>
        <h2>
            <li>
    <a id='7a' href='#'> Link1</a>
            </li>
        </h2>
        <h2>
            <li>
                <a id='8a' href='#'> Link 2 </a>
            </li>
        </h2>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='portfolioImageWrapper'>
    <div class='portfolioImage'><a href='#'><img class="img" src='#' alt='Image1' title='Image 1' id='7img' /></a></div><div class='portfolioImage'><a href='#'><img class="img" src='#' alt='Image 2' title='Image2' id='8img' /></a></div></div>
```

​CSS:

```
    .imgHover
{
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8JZy/60/)

You can toggle a different css class to your links for sure. Just modify this in jquery code (in the toggleClass function) and add the class to the css part

Comment: Thank you, this wasn't exactly what I needed, but it was great help for achieving it! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want that when you hover over a link, the image should get bordered and when you mouse out from the link, the border of the image should get removed ?

Also, when you hover over an image, the link should get colored and when you mouse out the image, the link should go back to its original color ?

If that is the requirement, this code might help:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.portfolioProject a').hover(
    function ()
    {
        var idElement = this.id;
        $("#" + idElement.replace('a', '') + "img").css('border', '2px solid #cdfc5d');
       $("#" + idElement + "a").css('color', '#cdfc5d');
    },
 function()
 {
     var idElement = this.id;
     $("#" + idElement.replace('a', '') + "img").css('border', 'none');
     $("#" + idElement + "a").css('color', 'white');     
 }
);


$('.portfolioImage img').hover(
    function ()
    {
        var idElement = this.id;
        $("#" + idElement.replace('img', '') + "a").css('color', '#cdfc5d');
        $("#" + idElement + "img").css('border', '2px solid #cdfc5d');
    },
    function()
    {
       var idElement = this.id
       $("#" + idElement.replace('img', '') + "a").css('color', 'blue');
       $("#" + idElement + "img").css('border', 'none');
    }
);


});
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B47Gu/

I have modified the fiddle, will this serve your purpose: http://jsfiddle.net/B47Gu/3/

Comment: Actually, I'd like to have two effects at the same time. When I hover over <a> I want <a> to change color and <img> to get border.

Comment: The code that I have written is just a modification of your code and can be improved further.